# how to fix this keylistener error in java swing

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

i am learning GUI in python and i don't know why keylistener isn't working  the action listener work fine but the keylistner ,nope.

i tried to make the keylistener method public 
i tried to implement it in the main class (in my case "GUIevents")

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUIevents extends JFrame 
{

    int buttonclicked = 0;
    JButton button;
    JTextField entry;
    JTextArea output;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    new GUIevents();    

    } // main

    public GUIevents()
    {

        // Form
        .....
        ///////

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        button = new JButton("click for event");    

        entry = new JTextField("",15);

        output = new JTextArea(20,20);



        // Listneres 

        ListenForButton bevent = new ListenForButton();

        button.addActionListener(bevent);

        ListenForKeys kevent = new ListenForKeys();

        entry.addKeyListener(kevent);


        // adding 
         ...
        ////

        this.setVisible(true);        

    } // gui event constructor


    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener
    {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getSource() == button)
            {

                buttonclicked++;

                System.out.println("button clicked " + buttonclicked + " times");

            }

        }

    } // listenforbutton

    private class ListenForKeys implements KeyListener
    {

        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            output.append("key hit: " + e.getKeyChar() + "\n");
        }

        public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
        {

        }

        public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent arg0)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

i get this error when i debug  and thank u ...........................................................................................................(i needed to add this so i can post sorry )

```
GUIevents.java:97: error: GUIevents.ListenForKeys is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
    private class ListenForKeys implements KeyListener
```

Comment: Java is case-sensitive, and so `public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)` is not the same as the (correct version) `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)`. Always prepend your method overrides with the `@Override` annotation so that you avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't override any of the KeyListener interface methods, check your spelling.  Java methods start with lowercase letters, you've capitalized the K in all your method definitions in the ListenForKeys class.

Comment: thank u bro ifeel  iam dump now 
it worked